# Troubleshoot on arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I would like to ask on how to add arrayformula to this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(QUERY({
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$AD$2:$AL;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$AM$2:$AU;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$AV$2:$BD;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$BE$2:$BM;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$BN$2:$BV;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$BW$2:$CE;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$CF$2:$CN;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$CO$2:$CW;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$CX$2:$DF;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2);
FILTER('Censimento PdiV'!$DG$2:$DO;'Censimento PdiV'!$B$2:$B = "ON";'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = $J2)
};"Select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9 where Col1 = 'Magazzino di Spedizione'")))
```

- [LINK TO FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SMpiOg447QsLOCC-hLPhtHJWqFSr48d8p9jQy985dn0/edit?usp=sharing)
- The idea is to filter shipping addresses like 'Censimento PdiV'!AD2:AL, 'Censimento PdiV'!AM2:AU and so on where 'Censimento PdiV'!AD2:AD = 'Magazzino di Spedizione' and 'Censimento PdiV'!AM2:AM = 'Magazzino di Spedizione and so on where 'Censimento PdiV'!B2:B = 'ON' and where 'Censimento PdiV'!$U$2:$U = 'Piattaforma Web'!$J2;J.
- This is how it should looks like.
  Note that if the first col is not 'Magazzino di Spedizione' the formula check 'Magazzino di Spedizione' in the second 10 set of col .

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxWbJ.jpg)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_AB2` of `Piattaforma Web` tab:*

```js
=let(rep_;{'Censimento PdiV'!B2:B\'Censimento PdiV'!U2:U}; grp_;'Censimento PdiV'!AD2:DO; size_;9;
     Σ;reduce(tocol(;1);sequence(columns(grp_)/size_;1;1;size_);lambda(a;c;vstack(a;{rep_\choosecols(grp_;sequence(size_;1;c))})));
     Λ;filter(Σ;index(Σ;;1)="ON";index(Σ;;3)="Magazzino di Spedizione");
     map(J2:J;lambda(Γ;if(Γ="";;torow(ifna(filter(choosecols(Λ;sequence(8;1;4));choosecols(Λ;2)=Γ)))))))
```

- *Make sure to clear the whole range of `column AB-extreme right` so that the above formula can freely expand to bottom side+right ways*

[image]

Comment: Hello there, can you explain a bit more this formula? I never sow a syntax like that and I would like to know something more about it. This formula works fine. Thanks.
I received an email. Is that you?

Comment: There is any how to contact rockinfreakshow?